# Common word for "patheticness"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> Feigning cold to be hugged. [...] in its purest form.

When I search on Google or Theraurus I just get its noun counterpart: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/pathetic. But I'm sure I'm missing a very obvious/commonly used synonyms. Any suggestions?

Comment: [*Patheticness*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22pathticness%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ik1GVaT_KYuzyATT6oBg#tbm=bks&q=%22patheticness%22) is not that uncommon.

Comment: The trouble is that calling someone pathetic because they feign cold to get a hug is not a synonym, it's a _value judgement_. The word does describe the cold-feigning person, it tell us what a tough-minded character like you (and BTW I agree with you) thinks of the behaviour. IOW it is normative not descriptive. Having said that, I offer you NEEDY.

Comment: @David Pugh My mistake. I couldn't think a better example for "patheticness".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can offer you a word that is not so common, but is quite poetic.

> ***pathos*** ([WordNet](http://poets.notredame.ac.jp/cgi-bin/wn?cmd=wn&word=pathos)): *a quality that evokes pity or sadness.*

And again from [The WordSmyth](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=pathos):

> ***pathos***: *a quality in life or art that evokes pity, sadness, or compassion.*

It has some more commonly-used synonyms, like ***pitifulness*** (or ***piteousness***) and, somewhere in the middle with a slightly different bent, ***poignancy***.

Comment: It's worth noting that *pathetic* is derived from *pathos* through the meaning *easily affected by pathos*.